# Generalizations of Sard-Smale Theorem

Tags: differential-topology, infinite-dimensional-manifolds, fredholm-operators

[Sard-Smale theorem](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2373250?seq=1) holds for Fredholm maps $f:M\rightarrow B$ between separable Banach manifolds $M,N$. There are some constrains relating the Fredholm index $\operatorname{ind}(f)$ of $f$ to its differentiablity class. More precisely, we need to require $f\in C^{r}$, where $r>\max{(\operatorname{ind}(f),0)}$.

I would like to know what are the generalizations of this theorem into two directions:

1. assuming weaker regularity on $f$;
2. assuming weaker structure on the spaces $M,N$.

For instance, I know that the result is valid for bounded Fréchet manifolds in the case where $f$ is Lipchitz (see [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11253-011-0478-z)). The result is also valid for some domains with empty interior (see [here](https://mpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de/47404/)).

I would also like to know if the above (or others) generalizations are maximal, in the sense that there are counterexamples in the case of weaker requirements.

Any help is welcome.